# What does XmlReader.Parse() do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, xmlreader

edit: The project is an old project and the below code is one class in there that handles the xml.

There is a question to get the xsd from an old legacy application, but all it seems to be doing is: xmlReader.ParseXml(fileName,outputFile); in the ProcessXml() method.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using Utilities;
namespace JobProcessor
{


public class XmlJob : Job
{
    #region variables
    private string      ftpServer;
    private string      ftpUserName;
    private string      ftpPassWord;
    private string      ftpDestination;
    ///<summary>The xml reader used to get validation information from the xmp parsing</summary>
    protected XmlReader xmlReader   = new XmlReader();

    private string      outputFile;


    public XmlJob(string fileName, string type) : base(fileName, type){
        ftpServer       = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[type + "-ftp"];
        ftpUserName     = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[type + "-ftpUser"];
        ftpPassWord     = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[type + "-ftpPass"];
        ftpDestination  = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[type + "-ftpDest"];
    }


    protected bool ConfigureXmlReader(){
        int    recType    = 0;

        try{
            //set up the record types (i.e. the elements that trigger a new record in the output
            while(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[type + "-RecordType" + recType.ToString("00")] != null){
                xmlReader.AddRecordType(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[type + "-RecordType" + recType.ToString("00")],recType.ToString("00"));
                recType++;
            }
            //store the number of types
            xmlReader.SetNoRecordTypes(recType);
        }catch(Exception e){
            HandleError("Error loading record types\r\n" + e.ToString() + "\r\n" + e.StackTrace + "\r\n");
            return(false);
        }

        try{
            //set up the fields which make up each record type
            for(int i=0;i<recType;i++){
                xmlReader.AddFieldsList(i,ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[type + "-" + i.ToString("00") + "Fields"]);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            HandleError("Error loading field list\r\n" + e.ToString() + "\r\n" + e.StackTrace + "\r\n");
            return(false);
        }
        return(true);
    }

    public override void RunJob(){
        outputFile = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".flat");

        if(!ConfigureXmlReader()){
            return;
        }

        if(!CheckInputFile()){
            return;
        }

        if(!ProcessXml()){
            return;
        }

        if(!Validate()){
            return;
        }

        if(ftpServer!=null && ftpUserName!=null && ftpPassWord!=null && ftpDestination!=null){
            if(!FtpFile()){
                return;
            }
        }

        MoveOriginalFile();
    }


    protected virtual bool Validate(){
        return(true);
    }

    protected bool ProcessXml(){
        /*
         * Process the xml file into a delimited format
         */

        try{
            xmlReader.ParseXml(fileName,outputFile);
        }catch(Exception e){
            HandleError("Error parsing XML file\r\n" + e.ToString() + "\r\n" + e.StackTrace + "\r\n");
            return(false);
        }
        return(true);
    }
    protected bool FtpFile(){
        try{
            FtpMethods.UploadFile(ftpServer,ftpUserName,ftpPassWord,outputFile,ftpDestination);
        }catch(Exception e){
            HandleError("Error FTPing file\r\n" + e.ToString() + "\r\n" + e.StackTrace + "\r\n");
            return(false);
        }
        return(true);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

What exactly does this command do? F1 doesn't find anything and searching google gets me to a lot of xmlTextReaders.

Comment: What is the type of the xmlReader instance here ?

Comment: The code you showed doesn't compile. `XmlReader` is an abstract class.

Comment: Post your real code, `XmlReader` is abstract and can't be instantiated.

Comment: System.Xml.XmlReader is abstract, so you must be using another type with the same name. Please could you give us the fully qualified name (i.e. with namespaces) of the XmlReader you're using?

Comment: `XmlReader` here is probably not the `System.Xml.XmlReader` found in the .NET Framework. Check where it comes from. Taking a wild guess, I say it takes a fileName, opens the file and parses the contents into XML and finally writes the XML result to the outputFile.

Comment: Also You didn't import the `System.Xml` namespace. the one you're referring to is a custom class in the `Utilities` namespace.

Comment: thanks for all the answers, should i delete this question as it won't be of any use to anyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `XMLReader` type here is from the *Utilities* library, not the `XMLReader` type of the *.NET*.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: After looking at the code it Looks Like XmlReader is a custom class (Given that no using statements for System.Xml exists) which most likely wraps around XDocument as explained below

It could be incorrectly named , the only Parse method I know that works with Xml is all the XmlElements in the System.Xml.Linq namespace. I.e.

```
XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

This will parse the xml, it will check that it is a valid xmlDocument and if it is it will load it as an XDocument (or whatever element)

Answer (score 2):

The `XmlReader` class you are using is a custom class, most likely it is `Utilities.XmlReader`. We can't say anything about it, because it is a class written by you or a co worker.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that ParseXml was an extension method of XmlReader, if MSDN / F1 help doesn't give any information about the method definition? Or possibly, the author of the code subclassed from XmlReader and added this method.

Answer (score 1):

The [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class doesn't have a `Parse` method.
Checkout what is the runtime-type of the `xmlReader` variable declared in your code, and then recheck the msdn.

Or else you meant the [`XDocument.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx).

**Update** after OP's edit
I didn't manage to find any `ParseXml` in the entire BCL.

**Update2** after OP's edit
The [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class is abstract and thus cannot be used as declared in your code.
We must conclude (Also because the `System.Xml` namespace was not imported to your file...) that the type of the `xmlReader` variable in your code is probably declared somewhere in the `Utilities` namespace, no one can guess how you (or anybody else) coded it.

As a side note, when using `XmlReader` or any other type that implements the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface, you have to take care of its disposal ([view link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)).